# How can I execute the collectionView methods of a class from another one?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, xib

I have my class CardSensors which is has a collectionView which is filled with another XIB

```
class CardSensors: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var botName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sensorsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var sensors = [[String: Any]]()

    var viewModel: NewsFeedViewModel! {
        didSet {
            setUpView()
        }
    }

    func setSensors(sensors: [[String: Any]]){
        self.sensors = sensors
    }

    static func loadFromNib() -> CardSensors {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CardSensor", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! CardSensors
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func setupCollectionView(){
        let nibName = UINib(nibName: "SensorCollectionViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main)
        sensorsCollectionView.register(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SensorCollectionViewCell")
    }

    func setUpView() {
        botName.text = viewModel.botName
    }

}

extension CardSensors: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SensorCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? SensorCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

        cell.dateLabel.text = sensors[indexPath.row]["created_at"] as? String
        cell.sensorType.text = sensors[indexPath.row]["type"] as? String
        cell.sensorValue.text = sensors[indexPath.row]["value"] as? String
        cell.sensorImage.image = UIImage(named: (sensors[indexPath.row]["type"] as? String)!)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return sensors.count
    }

}
```

Im creating an object in another class like this but I want this to call the methods of the collectionView for it to load the info.

```
let sensorView = CardSensors.loadFromNib()
sensorView.sensors = sensores
sensorView.setupCollectionView()
```

The problem is that the collectionView methods are never being called. What can I do to call them from my other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the data souce

```
 sensorsCollectionView.register(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SensorCollectionViewCell")
 sensorsCollectionView.dataSource = self
 sensorsCollectionView.reloadData()
```

Then inside your vc , make it an instance variable

```
var sensorView:CardSensors!

sensorView = CardSensors.loadFromNib()
sensorView.sensors = sensores
sensorView.setupCollectionView()
```